# JBoss Classloader Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, classloader, jboss-4.2.x

Running JBoss 4.2.3.GA and trying to deploy a WAR that is using Spring/Hibernate/JPA. I'm getting ClassCastExceptions (quite a lot of different ones) so I'm trying to setup a Classloader Repository for my WAR.

This is my catalog.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file

```
<jboss-web>
    <loader-repository> 
        com.moo.catalog:loader=catalogLoader
    </loader-repository> 
</jboss-web>
```

Pretty sure it is not working as I can see:

11:25:48,181 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:25:48,181 INFO  [Version] Hibernate EntityManager 3.2.1.GA
11:25:48,197 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:25:48,197 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.2.1.GA
11:25:48,197 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:25:48,197 INFO  [Environment] Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1

and I have 3.5.1-Final bundled in my war.

**I tried to find proof of it working in the logs, but cannot see anything. How do I tell if I have successfully setup a classloader repository? Is that even the correct configuration and the correct place?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I don't know where to look in the logs - but this [link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/enableclassloaderlogging) may help

Have you tried running it with your classloader isolated?  It may be that you're picking up the hibernate versions from server lib.  I think this will work for JBoss 4.2:

```
<jboss-web>
 <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
  <loader-repository>
     com.moo.catalog:loader=catalogLoader
     <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
  </loader-repository>
 </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

[More info here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration)

Comment: I can see it being created in the logs now, but I still get class cast exceptions. Thanks though